# How to filter Vaadin grid as default

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid, vaadin4spring

Hi I'm trying to write a grid filter in Vaadin framework. My aim is that a user has a combo box with dropdown list and can choose that he wants to see only entries from 3, 6, 9 weeks ago. I wrote it but I have a problem becasue it doesnt work as default filter. I mean if I open a page the grid is displayed without filter. I need first click on the button. Is it possible to filter grid by default, showing only 3 weeks entries?
How can I manage it?

```
     final ComboBox<Integer> timePeriodSelector = new ComboBox<>("Time Filter", Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9);
    timePeriodSelector.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
    timePeriodSelector.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    timePeriodSelector.setValue(3);
    timePeriodSelector.addValueChangeListener(this::onWeekChange);
```

...

```
private void onWeekChange(HasValue.ValueChangeEvent<Integer> event) {

    switch (event.getValue()) {
    case 3:
        dateToCompare = LocalDate.now().minusDays(21);
        break;
    case 6:
        dateToCompare = LocalDate.now().minusDays(42);
        break;
    case 9:
        dateToCompare = LocalDate.now().minusDays(63);
        break;
    default:
        dateToCompare = LocalDate.now().plusDays(21);
    }

    ListDataProvider<CcEvent> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<CcEvent>) eventsOverview.getDataProvider();
    dataProvider.setFilter(CcEvent::getReportingDate,
            date -> compareDates(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(), dateToCompare));
}

private Boolean compareDates(LocalDate dateFromTable, LocalDate dateFromFilter) {
    return dateFromTable.isBefore(dateFromFilter);
}
```

Comment: Change order of your calls. You should call first `addValueChangeListener` and right after that `setValue`. It should run the listener code and filter you container.

Answer (score 0):

that piece of code looks nice and is how the Grid filter is intented.
However all you have to do is switch your `setValue` call with your `addValueChangeListener` call.

Setting the listener before setting the value ensures that the `ValueChangedEvent` is triggered!

Comment: Do you mean I need to change the order of methods like here?         timePeriodSelector.addValueChangeListener(this::onWeekChange);
timePeriodSelector.setValue(3); It doesnt work :(

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought was all you needed to do.
I tried your code with an `addValueChangeListener( x -> Notification.show(x.toString())` and if setValue is called before the addValueChangeListener the Notification is not shown.

However if it is called afterwards the Notification is shown.

Comment: Another idea:
Is the Dataprovider for `eventsOverview` set by calling `setItems`or something similar? If by the time `setValue`is called the Dataprovider is not yet set there is no data for filtering available yet